# How to pass the value to HTML5 video tag src attribute in Android phonegap using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I created videoplayer in android phonegap using video tag in html5.

I containted 10 link.when I click that any one of the linkvalue of that link is passed into src attribute of video tag.and play that video.

Now I getvalue of link how to pass that value into src attribute of video tag in onclick event?

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The video tag is broken in the WebView class on Android. In order to work around this issie I created a VideoPlayer plugin for PhoneGap Android.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: Does it work if the source is provided as a data URI?

Answer (score 0):

cant u do a

```
$('#id').attr('src', linkvalue)
```

? this would pass the src to the video tag which would render the video

Comment: I use this link http://videojs.com/ for creating videoplayer in android phonegap. video player is created successfully.but video is not played.It;s work fine in browser,but not in emulator. how  to solve this problem.plwase guide me.it's urgent.thanks in advance